How to create a ComboBox in HTML?
Short Version
How can i make a ComboBox in HTML?
Long Version
How can I create an editable drop-down with default text in HTML?
Which is to say:

a text box the user can type in
or they can click (or Alt+Down) to display a drop-down
and select some pre-defined text
while the text box defaults to some useful default that does not (necessarily) appear in the list

Something like the standard Windows Combo Box control, or the WinForms ComboBox:

Research Effort
I've tried the following HTML:


<input id="edPhrase" list="phrases" value="Hello, world!">
<datalist id="phrases">
  <option value="Good morning Vietnam">Good morning Vietnam</option>
  <option value="Stay classy San Francisco">Stay classy San Francisco</option>
  <option value="Cleaveland Rocks">Cleaveland Rocks</option>
  <option value="I see dead people">I see dead people</option>
  <option value="Guess who's drunk">Guess who's drunk</option>
</datalist>



but no drop-down appears:

If the user deletes the existing text, then the drop-down will appear:

Thus defeating the entire purpose of a drop-down.
Which beings us to the question:

How can i make a ComboBox in HTML?

Complete Minimal Reproducible Example (CRME)
So you can try to fiddle with it to make it work in your sandbox:

jsFiddle: 7t1zgqo6


like this? https://jsfiddle.net/nwH8A/

@Roadman1991 Almost; except there's no default text.

A datalist is for autocompletion, it won't show all the options by default.

@0stone0 That means my Research Effort using an input and a datalist will go nowhere. Which leads me back to my question: How to create a ComboBox in HTML.

It'll require some JS for the autocompletion, there are some tools which provide such boxes, if you don't want any external libs, use a select with custom JS to enable autocompletion.

@0stone0 The answer seems to be "you cannot do it in HTML". That's fine. That's allowed to be the answer. If HTML simply cannot replicate one of the most commonly used user interface widgets for the last 34 years: that's the way it is. Write that in the form of an answer and it will be accepted.

There is no native HTML way of achieving that, you'll need some custom Javascript to make an <datalist> show all the options, or implement autocompletion on a <select>

Using a placeholder on the <input> will ensure all the options are shown inside the <datalist>, this will keep the filter while typing functions but you won't be able to 'select' the placeholder.


<input type="text" list="cars" placeholder="Choose..." />
<datalist id="cars">
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option>Saab</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
</datalist>




There are some tricks to let datalist always show every available input using (eg) blur() events if the placeholder isn't enough:

How can I make a browser display all datalist options when a default value is set?


Accepted as: not possible.

You need JavaScript to delete OR focus and select and they can start typing which will open the dropdown for what they type assuming the letter they type appears in the datalist


document.getElementById('edPhrase').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const input = e.target;
  input.value = "";
});
/* Perhaps not
document.getElementById('edPhrase').addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
  const input = e.target;
  if (input.value.trim() === "") input.value=input.defaultValue;
});
*/
document.getElementById('edPhrase').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const input = e.target;
  if (input.value.trim() !== "") input.defaultValue=input.value;
});
<input id="edPhrase" list="phrases" value="Hello, world!">
<datalist id="phrases">
  <option value="Good morning Vietnam">Good morning Vietnam</option>
  <option value="Stay classy San Francisco">Stay classy San Francisco</option>
  <option value="Cleaveland Rocks">Cleaveland Rocks</option>
  <option value="I see dead people">I see dead people</option>
  <option value="Guess who's drunk">Guess who's drunk</option>
</datalist>





document.getElementById('edPhrase').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const input = e.target;
  input.focus();
  input.select();
})
<input id="edPhrase" list="phrases" value="Hello, world!">
<datalist id="phrases">
  <option value="Good morning Vietnam">Good morning Vietnam</option>
  <option value="Stay classy San Francisco">Stay classy San Francisco</option>
  <option value="Cleaveland Rocks">Cleaveland Rocks</option>
  <option value="I see dead people">I see dead people</option>
  <option value="Guess who's drunk">Guess who's drunk</option>
</datalist>



Alternatively search for widgets

The drop-down doesn't appear (https://jsfiddle.net/1e8v3tgk/)

It does as soon as you type a letter that appears in the datalist

But it does not appear when the user clicks the drop-down ▼; which is the entire point. The revised snippet deletes the text when the user clicks the drop-down

See update. You can clear the field and restore it
